# Oauth in Flutter for Android App using Google Sign-In

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, google-signin

I am trying to use Google Sign-In to obtain a token in my Android app. I don't want to use Firebase, I want to use the token to sign into my own app and obtain a JWT token from it.

I can get this to work when I compile it to a Chrome app, but it crashes in Android after the redirect with the error "PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null))".

The code which does the sign in looks like this:

```
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class SignInGoogle {
  static final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      'email',
    ],
  );


  static void signInToGoogle() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;
      String? accessToken = googleAuth.accessToken;
      print('ACCESS TOKEN');
      print(accessToken);
    } catch(err) {
      print(err);
    }

  }
```

I have a home screen with a sign in button like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import '../network/google_sign_in.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
            SignInGoogle.signInToGoogle();
          }, child: const Text('Sign In'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

}
```

Can anyone help please.